# matlab: need help with formulating tricky bvp of 2nd order ode

Tags: matlab, boundary-value-problem

I tried to make the example as simple as possible:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}W=c_1 x^3\cdot\text{somefunc}(\frac{W+x^2\lambda}{c_2x^2})$$
which is defined for $0<x\leq1$.

$c_i$ are constants and $\lambda$ is an unknown parameter to be determined.

The boundary conditions are given as:
$$W(0)=c_3,\; W(1)=W'(1)=0$$

Further I have to use $W'=2xV$ so that $V'=c_1x^3\cdot \operatorname{somefunc}(\frac{W+\lambda x^2}{c_2x^2})$
.Dont ask me why I can't simply use $W'=V$, I dont't know. But I have to use that uncomfortable formulation for the first derivative.

That's what I have tried:

```
f = @(x,W,lambda)  [ W(2); 2*c1*(x^3)*somefunc((W(1)+(x^2)* lambda)/(c_2*x^2)];
g = @(ya,yb,lambda)[ya(1)-c_3; yb(2)-yb(1);yb(2)];  

solinit=bvpinit([0,1],[0,0],0);
sol = bvp4c(f,g,solinit);
```

Of course that's incorrect. I simply used $W'=V$ since I don't know better.

How can I get W(x)? 
Any hints?

edit:all constants as well as the function 'somefunc' is known.

Comment: Dear OD IUM: Kindly review my edits to help ensure the post expresses your question accurately, after my edits.

Comment: 1. You need to work within the format that bvp4c expects. The odefun takes x and then the vector y; the bcfun takes the vector ya and the vector yb. They can't take anything else.

Comment: 2. Your problem is not suitable for bvp4c in the first place because you don't fully know the odefun and because you have 3 BCs when you "should" have two. This makes your problem somewhat like an eigenproblem. My suggestion for solving it would be to treat it as a backward-in-time IVP (not a BVP), where you take guesses for $\lambda$ and from there you compute $W(0)$. Then you get a function $h$ mapping $\lambda$ to $W(0)$, and you try to solve the 1D equation $h(\lambda)=c_3$. This technique will work because you have an initial value and an initial derivative on the right end.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for your suggestion. That's what I've feared...This means I have to use the shooting method or some kind of it, right?

Comment: What I described is kind of like a shooting method except the variable that you are searching in is not a BC but rather a parameter. The principle is the same though: choose the parameter, solve an IVP, update the parameter, repeat until you've chosen a suitable value of the parameter. You could do it as a BVP as well, for instance by solving the BVP with $W(0)=c_3,W(1)=0$ and attempt to change $\lambda$ to make $W'(1)=0$. I suspect this will be slower than the IVP approach, though.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how to solve this problem if $W'=2xV$.

Comment: It's just a change of variables. $W'=2xV$ so $V'=\frac{d}{dx} \left ( \frac{W'}{2x} \right ) = \frac{2xW''-2W'}{4x^2}$. Plug in $W''$ from your ODE and plug in $W'=2xV$. My guess would be that this formulation is to help the solver to manage some kind of singularity.